# Too many threads - Impacting render performance

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have an application that fetches a lot of information from the web and displays it in a window with WPF. The information fetching is of course done in several background threads; most of them shouldn't be very calculation intensive (other than some text-parsing), but rely mostly on fetching webcontent (webclient.Download.. and similar).

Since I have to send A LOT of  requests, I start a lot of threads or the user would have to wait hours to complete loading everything; since many of those threads are mainly waiting on the data from network and / or starting new requests to a webservice, this shouldn't be a problem in theory. In practice, however, the dispatcher performance is often noticeably worse than without the threads running.

The background threads are created by a mix of TPL dataflow pipelines and Parallel.ForEach methods. I also already try to limit the amount of threads by specifying MaxThreads, but since any dataflow block can launch a Parallel.Foreach block, I don't think this works too well.

Is there any way to increase the dispatcher priority, performance or decrease stuttering any other way?

Edit: Amount of tasks/threads is normally between 50-100, maybe a little more in the worst case. A typical scenario of a weblookup is: Send request to webservice, parse response (<10kb string). For each response, (parallel.foreach) download data for this response, download/cache any images from the response and parse the response (e.g., remove any links from a wikipedia article); wait for them all to complete and move to next lookup.

Comment: Are you dispatching an update to the UI (to show progress etc) during the ForEach within the dataflow block? If so you could try only dispatching to the UI every 250ms. Done this before with good results :)

Comment: I think posting your code could help decide the amount of CPU vs IO bound work you're doing.

Comment: When you say "too many threads", could you give us an estimate to how many threads you have running? Is it 10? 100? 1000? 10000?

Comment: @Tom only once a dataflow block is finished, which is more than a few seconds apart, the background threads should be independent

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov code isn't practical, but I added a typical scenario of what a thread performs.

Comment: What does it matter that data flow blocks can call Parallel.ForEach? Just put them all on the same task scheduler http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180376/limit-of-outgoing-connections-for-one-process-net/19180845

Answer (score 1):

Instead of starting a new thread to download the data consider using the asynchronous versions of the downloading functions like `WebClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync`. Then you don't need to start a thread. Simply call

```
var result = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync
```

and process the result after the `await`. This will basically kick off the download operation and return. Once the download is completed the rest of the method will be executed. And best of all it doesn't use any extra threads.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no code example, and by the tone of your post, it looks to me like you could completely save the usage of using threads supplied by either `TPL Datablock` or `Parallel.ForEach` by using async IO based pattern.

If your main objective is to download webcontent, i would try the `Task Asynchronous Pattern` based approach. For example, this is using [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx)

```
public async Task<string> DownloadWebContentAsync(string url)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    // Assuming a GET request
    var response = await client.GetAsStringAsync(url);

    // Do some string processing..

    return response;
}
```

Now, consume it:

```
await DownloadWebContentAsync(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear to me that your background threads do not cause much CPU load as you say. Even if on average they cause little load the load might be spiking and lead to stuttering.

Try putting the background work on a `TaskScheduler` with low priority. The Parallel Extension Extras have a `TaskScheduler` that supports that.

How often are you updating the UI? Maybe it is too often. Throttle the frequency of updates.

How many threads are we talking about anyway? If the number goes into the hundreds consider using async IO. An async IO operation does not use a thread while it is running. Not even a background thread.

Comment: CPU utilization stays between 30-60% on all four cores of mine. The UI has some very ugly calculations and effects that have a rather heavy impact on performance, but it seems to work smoothly with no threads running in the background; it's also rather hard to optimize since all effects and animations are needed.

I will definitely try using async and the task scheduler, thanks!