# async/await and multiprocessing

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous, dotnet-httpclient

I have txt file with 50 000 000 unique domain names and at first I'm trying to only open each site. I'm using async HttpClient and tryied 3 diffrent methods to split the tasks:

## 1

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines("file.txt");
try
{
    DataSet allData;
    var downloadData = new TransformBlock<string,byte[]>(
    async line =>
    {
        HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage =
            await client.GetAsync(line).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return
            await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //catch all to reduce code for testing
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref finishedUrls);
        }
    },
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 500,
    });
    foreach (var line in lines)
    downloadData.Post(line);
    downloadData.Complete();
    await downloadData.Completion;
```

## 2

```
List<Task> allTasks = new List<Task>();
SemaphoreSlim throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded);
foreach (var line in lines)
{

    await throttler.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    allTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
    {

            try
            {
                HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(line).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    var byteArray = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
                Interlocked.Increment(ref finishedUrls);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            throttler.Release();
        }
    }));
}
await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
```

## 3

```
await lines.ForEachAsync(500,cancellationToken,async line =>
{
    HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(line).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var byteArray = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    Interlocked.Increment(ref finishedUrls);
}
);

public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, CancellationToken cancellationToken,
            Func<T, Task> body)
        {
            return Task.WhenAll(
                from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop).AsParallel()
                select Task.Run(async delegate
                {
                    using (partition)
                        while (partition.MoveNext())
                            await body(partition.Current).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }, cancellationToken));
        }
```

The best speed results I have from #3 solution - about 12 000 urls/min and 10 000 connections estabilished in Performance Monitor - cpu used ~1%

But when I split txt file to 5 parts = 10 000 000 urls in each file and run 5 instances of my program the summary speed is 25 000 urls / min and 30 000 connections estabilished - cpu used in 3%. I was playing with increasing partionion numbers from 500 to more but it doesnt bring big changes. So my question is - how to run one instance of program which can handle 25 000 urls / min? How to divide that async jobs to get the highest possible speed?

Is there any .NET limits for process?

The program is running on 64bit windows server 2012
500Mb network, 64GB RAM, SSD disk, E5-1620-v2 CPU

**UPDATE 1**
Speed results for diffrent "dop" and 4 instances simultanesouly:
http://pastebin.com/ab3UQPAC

Comment: This depends a lot on the hardware it is running on. How do you expect us to answer this?

Comment: I have wrote that hardware can easy handle summary 25 000 urls/min in 5 instances

Comment: I know you have mentioned about the partitioning, but have you increased it to 5x as much?

Comment: Yes I have tryid with 2500 partitions - and even 5000 partitions - speed doesnt increase much - only to 13000-14000 urls/min

Comment: Whats the CPU profile for that 2500/5000 compared to 500

Comment: For only url download CPU is on very low usage - 500 partitions - 1-2%, 5000 partitions - 3-5% So I think CPU usage is not problem here

Comment: OK, Does the TPL shcedule tasks on the ThreadPool?  Try increasing threadpool as well as partition  ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads ThreadPool.SetMinThreads

Comment: Also, you are creating a task outside of HttpClient Tasks per line.  The HttpClient tasks will be IO bound, however the other Task could be threadpool bound.  Can it be rewriten without the external wrapping task?  allTasks.Add(

Comment: Try a ContinueWith after  instread of client.GetAsync(line) to include the parsing logic.  Then WhenAll on the returned tasks rather than running each line in a task

Comment: I think, most of the time your code waits for HTTP response. It's possible you can't to accelerate it greatly.

Comment: @JamesSimpson I have testing speed with solution #3. I havent got any parsing in  my code yet - all code for test is in question.

Comment: Can you try the answer below.  Task.Run is putting things on the threadpool.   Also increase threadpool size?

Comment: @MarkShevchenko - but why I can reach 25 000 urls/min on 5 instances but can't do it on one? - this is the problem - and I've asked it is possible or I need to run it on multi proccesses

Comment: `30 000 connections estabilished`! Sounds like lingering keep-alive connections. You don't need those since it appears you are only requesting about one URL per domain. Anyway, this is likely not your problem (except if this causes contention in the BCL). Measure how fast you can go when you increase the DOP from 500 and post the results. Test 1k, 2k, 4k, 8k. This should work. Try running this outside of the debugger. Maybe the debugging features ruin task scalability at such levels.

Comment: @usr Just posted results for diffrent DOP and 4 instances running at the same time. No debbuger - release x64

Comment: Have you tried disposing of `HttpClient` instances between requests, such as with `using` statements? Grasping at straws a little here but it's possible that at some critical mass things could bog down with all those instances hanging around.

Comment: 2 other straw-grasping suggestions: 1) Don't ignore exceptions, at least while testing, just to be sure none are being thrown. 2) Do you actually need the returned byte arrays or do you just sort of want to ping the sites to check if they're available or something? If the latter, do HEAD requests instead of GETs.

Comment: @ToddMenier disposing HttpClient slows down I have already tested this, the same when using one instance of HttpClient. I don't ignore exceptions just deleted it for SO code samples. Also I'm measuring speed only for good results. I need byte array in next step when I resolve problems with speed

Answer (score 0):

Removing the outer task might help?

something along the lines off (minus exception handling?)

```
List<Task> allTasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var line in lines)
{
            HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
            try
            {
            allTasks.Add(client.GetAsync(line).
            ContinueWith(t => t.Result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion));
            }
            catch
            {
            }
}
await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
```

If could be conceivable that you are consuming too many ThreadPool resources by having an outer tasks that is awaiting on the response?  Not sure on the specifics of how the scheduler would deal with this, however the outer task looks redundant to me.

Comment: Why did it stop?  You still might need to throttle it.  E.g how long did it take to get to 15,000 urls.  Also you probably want to keep the context switching option in there (e.g ConfigureAwait(false).  Basically follow option 2, but remove the Task.Run? and use the ContinueWith instead?

Comment: Did it crash because of the lack of exception handling?  Maybe it was skipping URLS before.  I have added a try catch

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` to a very high number, such as `int.MaxValue`.

Comment: The same answer was posted before by @schglurps - limit is per domain

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is related to this : [Limit of outgoing connections for one process (.Net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180376/limit-of-outgoing-connections-for-one-process-net)
Try to increase the maximum number of connections to the number of tasks (probably the number of cores) you run concurrently.

Comment: Number of connection is limited per domain - as I said I have "unique" domains list

Comment: OK, didn't understand, sorry